# auto keyword is not deducing type of string

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu-12.04, g++4.8

I've this simple code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1 = "rohit";
    auto len = s1.size();

    cout << len;
}
```

When I compile this code on Ubuntu 12.04, it shows following error:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:8:10: error: ‘len’ does not name a type
     auto len = s1.size();
          ^
test.cc:10:13: error: ‘len’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << len;
             ^
```

I've got **g++ 4.8.1**. Is there some changes with the usage of `auto` keyword in g++ 4.8.1?

Comment: Try compiling with `-std=c++11`

Comment: @yngum. Well, that worked. And that surprises me. Ain't I having c++11 on my system? I've latest version of `g++` already.

Comment: @RohitJain: You need to enable C++11 compilation in G++ by specifying the `std = c++11` compiler flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `error: ‘len’ does not name a type` leads me to believe that you didn't compile in C++11 mode and that it's using the old, C++98 meaning of the keyword `auto`.

Comment: @MarkB.. That worked. And that surprises me. Ain't I having c++11 on my system? I've latest version of g++ already.

Comment: @RohitJain Having C++ 11 support is not the same as it being the default setting of your compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3. Ok. So, how I should set the default setting?

Comment: @RohitJain Read the answer?

Comment: @H2CO3. Yeah read it. Isn't there any way to set it and avoid passing as argument? Do I always have to use `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @RohitJain If your compiler wasn't set up to have it as default, then you do. Maybe you can write a shell script that does the job for you? Even better, use `make` for build automation, and then you only have to write it once.